# Why do we do delete [object].[property] inside of tearDown (unit testing)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, buster.js

**Code:**

```
var buster = require('buster'),
    NumberCruncher = require('../src/NumberCruncher');

buster.testCase('Number Cruncher', {
    setUp: function() {
        this.numberCruncher = new NumberCruncher();
    },
    tearDown: function() {
        delete this.numberCruncher;
    },
    'constructor returns numberCruncher': function() {
        assert(this.numberCruncher instanceof NumberCruncher);
    },
    'object constructor correct': function() {
        assert.equals(this.numberCruncher.constructor, NumberCruncher);
    },
    'can add numbers': function() {
        buster.assert.equals(this.numberCruncher.add(5,3), 8, 'NumberCruncher cannot add');
    }
});
```

**Background:**

In `setUp`, we are creating an object and setting it as a property of `this` (the testcase). In `tearDown` we are deleting said property.

**Question:**

If you had to explain the thought or reason behind the practice of deleting object properties in the `tearDown` method, what would you say? Why is this a good thing? Does it have benefits? Does it only have benefits when scaled to really big objects?

**My Thoughts:**

My reasoning (which may be wrong), is that we are guaranteeing garbage collection after each test is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not garbage collection is being guaranteed is irrelevant. More important is resetting the value to a known state (in this case, undefined) so that there is no chance of creating a false positive or false negative test case by having dirty data from the last one.

Comment: But if setUp gets called at the start of each test and the value is overridden, isn't the chance of creating a false positive removed?

Comment: In that case yes, but if you are initializing the value (or not) in a test case, then it's much easier to make a mistake. I'm not sure I understand why you need to know, honestly.